# Script won't move file

Tags: php, html, file, upload

Hello I would like to upload multiple files with a php script. It recognises all the files, but doesn't move them to the right folder and it isn't giving any errors.

this is the php code

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadImage'])){
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['upload']['size']);$i++){
        if(strstr($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i], 'image')!==false){
            $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($name, "../_/upload");
            echo $name;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the html

```
<form name="formAdd" method="post" action="../control/checkCall.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" value="" name="upload[]" multiple>
<button type="submit" name="uploadImage">Upload!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked for access privileges?

Answer (score 2):

Change following line

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i],"../../upload/".$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself (if its not already done) :

-Does move_uploaded_file() realy is called ?

-Does move_uploaded_file() works ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it doesn't work because when you load the file, it gets a temporary file name, which you need to use as your move_uploaded_file  parameter.

try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadImage'])){
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['upload']['size']);$i++){
        if(strstr($_FILES['upload']['type'][$i], 'image')!==false){
            $tname = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($tname, "../_/upload");
            echo $tname;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check the upload/ directory has 755 chmod permissions in FTP